# Globalization Analysis for XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017, code-analysis, globalization

Using Visual Studio 2017 Code Analysis, I get warnings when the text in any .cs files hasn't been localized.

For example, the below code generates [CA1303](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1303-do-not-pass-literals-as-localized-parameters?view=vs-2017):

```
this.tb1.Text = "Hello World! tb2";
```

> Method 'MainWindow.MainWindow()' passes a literal string as
>   parameter 'value' of a call to 'TextBlock.Text.set(string)'. Retrieve
>   the following string(s) from a resource table instead: "Hello World!
>   tb2"

Is there anything available that can do the same for XAML? For example, I'd want a warning if it found the following:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tb2" Text="Hello world - tb2!"/>
```

Preferably free but could consider paid-for solutions.

Comment: I think StyleCop support this already.

Comment: @Nekeniehl I've just tried and can't see it anywhere in StyleCop. Do you have any more info?